# border-radius.htc support for hiding/showing divs?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, html-components

I'm using border-radius.htc to simulate the `border-radius` CSS property in IE.  It works fine, but I want to show and hide a div with rounded corners.

The problem is that the border-radius.htc does not support advanced manipulation like hiding div, only modifying the size.

Has anyone experienced similar problems and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [css3pie](http://css3pie.org) for rounded corners on ie6 and up.

Use PIE with the behavior tag which will not effect any other browsers except ie6/7/8:

`.rounded-borders{
 border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 behavior:url(PIE.htc); /* Will not effect other browsers */
}`

IE9 will have native support for rounded corners. This script takes that into account.

Comment: Just make sure you add the mime type for h&c to your htaccess, and ensure it's cached properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to recommend http://www.curvycorners.net/. Pushing an .htc isn't really the best option out there - I actually haven't seen that in years. Plus IE could drop support whenever!

I have heard rumors of native border radius in IE9!

Best of luck to you =D